# Is GAP (graph accessibility) NP-Complete?

Tags: graph, np-complete

Is the GAP (graph accessibility problem) NP-Complete ?
It has polynomial and non-deterministic polynomial algorithms that solve it, but I don't think this is a criteria that overrides the basic way of showing it's NP-Complete, by showing it is NP and NP-Hard => NP-Complete.
I heard both versions from older students than me.
So in the end, is it or not NP-Complete?

Comment: If it has a polynomial algorithm, how could it be NP?

Comment: From what my course material says, P is included in NP. Also to demonstrate that a problem is in NP you have to build a non-deterministic algorithm OR prove that a solution can be verified in polynomial time.

Comment: From how I understood your question, you have a non-deterministic algorithm for finding the solution. In that case, the problem is either not NP-Complete, or you just proved that `P=NP`, which while possible seems extremely unlikely ;).

Comment: P is INCLUDED (not EQUAL) in NP. The course material says that in order to demonstrate that a problem is NP-Complete it must be NP and NP Hard.
To show that is NP it states that you must provide an NP algorithm or show that the solution can be verified in polynomial time.
To show that is NP Hard it states that you must reduce a known NP Hard problem to the current one.
Also: http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/files/1000px-P_np_np-complete_np-hard-e1347048707765-245x300.png

Comment: Sorry, I keep mistyping ^^. I meant NP-Complete in my first comment and deterministic (not non-deterministic) in my second. So if you have a deterministic polynomial algorithm for finding a solution, your problem is in P. If it is also NP-Hard, it is NP-Complete. That would prove that `P=NP`.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St-connectivity) says that the problem is `NL-Complete`, which means that it’s also in `P`. This makes it extremely unlikely that it is `NP-Complete`. If it was, that would prove that [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P=NP), which is a very old and unsolved question. And it is widely assumed that `P≠NP`.

You won’t be able to prove that it is not `NP-Complete` either, [because that would prove `P≠NP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate).

If you can prove that it is `NP-Complete` or that it is not `NP-Complete`, you will recieve [an award of one million dollars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems).

So in summary the answer is: It seems very unlikely, but it is just as unlikely that you can prove anything in that direction :).